# Using scenes to create an assembly instruction

Tags: scene

We at my company are trying to make an assembly instruction of our product with the help of Blender. We want to do a IKEA style instruction with a series of assembly step (ca 10 steps), each in order, how to demount objects, move objects and then remount them in order. We then want to render each step and publish them. As I see it I have two options.

1. Use one Blend files for each step, based on the original model. (Not very efficient since there may be changes to the original model in the future)
2. Use the Scenes function in Blender, and make as many scenes as needed, with each assembly step in each Scene.

But what I cant figure out is how to keep the Blend file not becoming extremely big and heavy and to keep the transformations in each Scene separated. I tried the Linked copy of the model, in each scene, but then every transformation I make in one Scene gets copied to the others. For example, I move a plate. That plate gets moved in the other scenes as well.

[image]

I guess my question is: is there a way to use the Linked copy command and keep transformations in each scene separated?
Or is there a better way of working with these issues?

Comment: Another option would be to use animations to change object positions relative to each other starting from the assembled object.That way you are able keep everything in one file (or link from other files if there are several sub-assemblies) and have every step be just a bunch of keyframes